# Use ddply to summarize data for different ranges of column values

Tags: r, plyr

I have the following data frame:

```
structure(list(a = c(0, 0, 0, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1
), b = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), value = c(0.638197756838053, 
0.655913984635845, 0.261592486174777, 0.442856104113162, 0.993114325450733, 
0.610009586671367, 0.573423251975328, 0.44579351413995, 0.0946824024431407
)), 
.Names = c("a", "b", "value"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

result

```
     a b     value
1 0.00 1 0.6381978
2 0.00 2 0.6559140
3 0.00 3 0.2615925
4 0.05 1 0.4428561
5 0.05 2 0.9931143
6 0.05 3 0.6100096
7 0.10 1 0.5734233
8 0.10 2 0.4457935
9 0.10 3 0.0946824
```

I want to generate the mean of `value` for different ranges of `b` in a **single data frame**. I am doing this naively and manually like this:

1)  I want the mean of `value` for `b` up to `1`, grouped by `a`:

```
> b1 <- ddply(subset(result, b==1),.(a),summarize,meanValue = mean(value))
> b1
     a meanValue
1 0.00 0.6381978
2 0.05 0.4428561
3 0.10 0.5734233
```

2) I want the mean of `value` for `b` up to `2`, grouped by `a`:

```
> b2 <- ddply(subset(result, b<=2),.(a),summarize,meanValue = mean(value))
> b2
     a meanValue
1 0.00 0.6470559
2 0.05 0.7179852
3 0.10 0.5096084
```

3) I want the mean of `value` for `b` up to `3`, grouped by `a`:

```
> b3 <- ddply(subset(result, b<=3),.(a),summarize,meanValue = mean(value))
> b3
     a meanValue
1 0.00 0.5185681
2 0.05 0.6819933
3 0.10 0.3712997
```

Then, later I add a column to each dataframe, indicating which one it is (`b1`,`b2` or `b3`) and `rbind` them all into a single data frame.

There must be a simpler/cleaner/smarter way of doing this but I can't think of anything.

Comment: How about looping with lapply i.e. `lapply(1:3, function(x) {x1 <- subset(result, b<=x); ddply(x1, .(a), summarise, meanValue=mean(value))})`

Comment: That is a good solution!
I would adapt it to:

`Reduce(rbind,lapply(1:3, function(x) {x1 <- subset(result, b<=x); cbind(ddply(x1, .(a), summarise, meanValue=mean(value)),maxB=x)}))`

So I can have a `maxB` column and a single data frame. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: @jonathancardoso, I think you could probably wrap up akruns suggestion to use `merge` instead `rbind` as in `l <- lapply(1:3, function(x) {x1 <- subset(result, b<=x); ddply(x1, .(a), summarise, meanValue=mean(value))}) ; Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = "a"), l)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including the comments from @jonathancardoso for "multiple" functions

```
library(plyr)
res <- do.call(rbind,lapply(unique(result$b), function(x) {
          x1 <- subset(result, b<=x)
          cbind(ddply(x1, .(a), summarise,
               meanValue=mean(value)),maxB=x)}))
```